# Wrap ControlValueAccessor in another Component

Tags: angular, angular7, controlvalueaccessor, ng-container

For a side project, I have made a new implementation of ControlValueAccessor (a matrix selection AKA: a table where you can select and de-select cells). An options Input can be supplied to change how the matrix behaves in response to user interaction.

I am trying to create an "examples" page to list several matrix selection controls with various options set (a little like this: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview). For each example, I would like to show the bound value json which updates as a user interacts with the control and the options json.

This is simple to do but repetitive (I have many more variations than supplied below):

```html
<h1>Matrix Selection Component</h1>
<h2>Basic</h2>
<app-matrix-selection [formControl]="peopleAttributesControl"></app-matrix-selection>
<h3>Json</h3>
<pre>{{data|json}}</pre>
<h3>Options</h3>
<pre>{{options||json}}</pre>

<h2>With Labels</h2>
<app-matrix-selection [formControl]="peopleAttributesControl" [keys]="people" [selectables]="subjects" firstCellValue="Students / Subjects"></app-matrix-selection>
<h3>Json</h3>
<pre>{{data|json}}</pre>
<h3>Options</h3>
<pre>{{options||json}}</pre>
...
```

Notice that for each example I have to output the json and options values.

In my head (probably wrongly), what I'd like to do is something like:

```html
<h1>Matrix Selection Component</h1>
<h2>Basic</h2>
<app-example>
   <app-matrix-selection [formControl]="peopleAttributesControl"></app-matrix-selection>
</app-example>

<h2>With Labels</h2>
<app-example>
   <app-matrix-selection [formControl]="peopleAttributesControl" [keys]="people" [selectables]="subjects" firstCellValue="Students / Subjects"></app-matrix-selection>
</app-example>
...
```

And define AppExampleComponent in such a way that it can output the data and options of any component passed in (not just the selection matrix but anything else I might define with said properties).

I am struggling to find any resources to help me achieve this and I think that may be because I'm struggling to word what it is I am trying to achieve. I want a component to wrap another component so that it can show me the effects of interacting with that component.

I suppose other ways of achieving are option 1:

```html
<h1>Matrix Selection Component</h1>
<h2>Basic</h2>
<app-matrix-selection [formControl]="peopleAttributesControl"></app-matrix-selection>
<app-example [data]="peopleAttributes"></app-example>

<h2>With Labels</h2>
<app-matrix-selection [formControl]="peopleAttributesControl" [keys]="people" [selectables]="subjects" firstCellValue="Students / Subjects"></app-matrix-selection>
<app-example [data]="peopleAttributes" [options]="withLabelsOptions"></app-example>
...
```

or option 2:

```html
<h1>Matrix Selection Component</h1>
<app-matrix-selection-example title="Basic" [data]="peopleAttributes"></app-matrix-selection-example>

<app-matrix-selection-example title = "With Labels" [data]="peopleAttributes" [keys]="people" [selectables]="subjects" firstCellValue="Students / Subjects" [data]="peopleAttributes" [options]="withLabelOptions"></app-matrix-selection>
...
```

but I really don't want to create an example component for every future ControlValueAccessor I create.

I feel like there's a key bit of Angular capability I'm missing here. If not, how would you approach this?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution One - Using ng-content**

I had forgotten a very basic concept - content children! The following link helped: https://medium.com/@tkssharma/understanding-viewchildren-viewchild-contentchildren-and-contentchild-b16c9e0358e

Forgetting the data and options requirement for a moment, this will result in:

```html
<app-example title="Basic">
    <app-matrix-selection [formControl]="peopleAttributesControl"></app-matrix-selection>
</app-example>
```

The example component then looks like this:

```html
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

The ng-content outputs the elements defined with the  element tags to screen.

**Solution Two - Dynamic Component Loader**

Part two of the requirements requires a dynamic component loading: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Having moved my examples to a service, I ended up with the following template:

```html
<h1>Matrix Selection Component</h1>
<app-example *ngFor="let example of examples" [title]="example.title" [example]="example"></app-example>
```

Much cleaner!

One of the example object's properties is an Angular core component type which can be dynamically loaded using ComponentFactoryResolver in the app-example component. Follow the instructions in the Angular.io link above.

The example component's template can then take care of the repeating structure:

```html
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
<ng-template appExample></ng-template>
<h3>Bound Data Json</h3>
<pre>{{ example.componentAttributes.data | json }}</pre>
<div *ngIf="example.componentAttributes.options">
    <h3>Options Json</h3>
    <pre>{{ example.componentAttributes.options | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

The caveat of this is that all my future components must have data and options properties which is enforced by implementing an interface - but that's fine for my purposes.